# bash + divide number with round number to up or down

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, bc

I want to convert 8874M to GIGA
so I did this

```
  echo $(( 8874 / 1024 ))
```

but actually we get 8 ( while exactly results is 8.6 )

so what need to change in order to get the 8.6?

Comment: I'm downvoting this because you just asked virtually the same question 50 minutes ago and you must not have read any of the answers/comments from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash doesn't do floating point arithmetics. Use `bc -l` instead:

```
bc -l <<< 'scale = 1; 8874 / 1024'
```

By setting `scale` to 1, you get the "exact" result 8.6, not the real exact result of 8.66601562500000000000.

Comment: its not work when I put the variable inside bc -l <<< 'scale = 1; $NUM / 1024'

Comment: Variables are expanded in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: @jango: Please read the following: [Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting)